# Maven compiler plugin -- intermittent compilation failure with JDK 14+

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Maven compiler plugin intermittently throws the following error with JDK 14, 15, and 16 but the build works successfully with JDK 11, 12, and 13:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project killbill-platform-lifecycle: Compilation
> failure

[Click here for full build failure logs.](https://github.com/killbill/killbill-oss-parent/runs/4724341549?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:4161)

The maven's `-X` and `-e` switches are not giving any relevant information.

The compilation fails on different modules on every build execution.

Using the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${check.skip-enforcer}</skip>
        <fail>${check.fail-enforcer}</fail>
        <failFast>false</failFast>
        <rules>
            <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
            <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
            <requireMavenVersion>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
            </requireMavenVersion>
            <requireJavaVersion>
                <version>11</version>
            </requireJavaVersion>
            <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                <maxJdkVersion>11</maxJdkVersion>
            </enforceBytecodeVersion>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- See profiles section for <release> configuration -->
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <source>16</source> <!--Tried different source/target versions-->
        <target>16</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <maxmem>${build.jvmsize}</maxmem>
        <failOnWarning>${compiler.fail-warnings}</failOnWarning>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
        <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Configure manifold plugin -->
            <!-- Disabled as it caused issues compiling in IntelliJ with Java11
                 e.g Class XXX is public, should be declared in a file XXX.java
            <arg>-Xplugin:Manifold</arg>
            -->
            <!-- Allow access to internal packages -->
            <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
            <arg>-J-Xss4m</arg>
            <arg>-J-noverify</arg>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
        <!-- Add the processor path for the plugin -->
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>systems.manifold</groupId>
                <artifactId>manifold-preprocessor</artifactId>
                <version>2021.1.11</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Profile:

```
   <profile>
    <id>javac-release</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <surefireArgLine>-Xmx${build.jvmsize} -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m</surefireArgLine>
    </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Please show more context of the failure ...not only that line...there more in the output....

Comment: Remove all jvm flags and Try again.

Comment: @khmarbaise Kindly check the link added in the question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Tried removing jvm flags but the results are the same.

Comment: Really ? I should scan through the whole output... Posting it here would be helpful... furthermore I checked only some lines and saw many many compiler WARNINGs etc. during the build... What I don't understand why the parent is building sub projects instead of the project which contains the modules ... (really confusing to be honest)...

Comment: Also using extreme old plugins like `maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin` ???? Why?

Comment: Try to remove the mysql part which fails to compile...It might also be the case that the preprocessor might have an issue and also upgrade that preprocessor because the version you are using a bit out-of-date...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your time on this issue. Your comments were very helpful. I had to remove the `manifold-preprocessor` dependency (update didn't work) to fix the intermittent compilation failures. Please feel free to add this as an answer. Thanks again.